# How do I align a split environment to the left?

Tags: equations, align, split

Consider:

```
\begin{flalign}
\begin{split}
\text{Consider a function}:   \pi:N \times N \rightarrow N  & \\
           \text{such that}:  &  \\
    \pi (k_{1},k_{2}):= \frac{1}{2}(k_{1}+k_{2})(k_{1}+k_{2}+1)+k_{2}  \forall \left ( k_{1},k_{2} \right )\epsilon N^{2} & \\ 
\end{split} 
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: Aside: Please don't write `\epsilon` to denote "is element of". Instead, please write `\in`.

Comment: Not very clear: do you want the whole block to be left-aligned, but each line to be right-aligned inside the block?

Comment: @Bernard text to be left aligned and mathematical expression center aligned

Comment: The use `\intertext`, or `\shortintertext` (from `mathtools`).

Answer (score 3):

If it fits what you want, you could use:

```
\noindent Consider a function:\quad  $\displaystyle \pi\colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$\\
such that:
\begin{equation}
  \pi (k_{1},k_{2}) := \frac{1}{2}(k_{1}+k_{2})(k_{1}+k_{2}+1)+k_{2}  \forall \left ( k_{1},k_{2} \right )\in \mathbb{N}^{2}  \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use `\displaystyle` for an inline-math formula?

Comment: Because I wanted to treat it as a display formula preceded by text.

Comment: I suppose it makes no difference for the inline equation at hand if it's typeset using text style or display style. It would only matter if you had terms such as `\frac` and `\sum`, right?

Comment: I haven't actually checked whether it made a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend that you *not* mix running text and mathematical formulas in the displayed equations. Instead, how about

[image]

Some fine points of mathematical typesetting to keep in mind: (a) Write `\in` rather than `\epsilon` to denote membership in a set; (b) write `\colon` rather than `:` in the first equation; (c) assuming "N" denotes the set of integers, you may wish to emulate near-universal typographic practice and write `\mathbb{N}` rather than just `N`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Consider a function 
\begin{gather}
\pi\colon\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \\
\intertext{such that}
\pi (k_1,k_{2}) \mathrel{:=} \frac{1}{2}(k_1+k_2)(k_1+k_2+1)+k_2 
\quad\forall\ (k_1,k_2)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}\,. \notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In a two-column IEEEtran class document, one would write:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Consider a function 
\begin{gather}
\pi\colon\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \\
\intertext{such that}
\pi (k_1,k_2) \mathrel{:=} \frac{1}{2}(k_1+k_2)(k_1+k_2+1)+k_2 \ \forall\ (k_1,k_2)\in\mathbb{N}^2\,. \notag
\end{gather}
(Some more text \emph{after} the equation.)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a technical difference between `\intertext` and `\text` when used inside math environment?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - Absolutely: The argument of `\intertext` -- short for "interline text", I suppose -- is placed on a line by itself; that's not the case for the argument of `\text`.

Comment: @Mico Please tell me a solution to reduce whitespace in your solution

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi - I assume you're referring to the second line: How about removing the `\quad` directive? (That's what I did for the version shown in the addendum...)